# MinGW installed in windows but still throwing error in while go run

Tags: go, gcc, mingw

I was initially facing the error during running a server code for go lang and the error in the import lines of the code

```
import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"log"

"github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka")
```

The error it was thrown was to check for executable gcc in the %PATH% variable

```
# github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka 
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

To rectify this i have installed MinGW gcc compiler and include in the path
Checked it in the terminal

```
g++ (tdm64-1) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This throwing the same error can anyone please tell me how to rectify this in windows 10.

EDIT:

This was resolved by restarting the terminal
The issue was even after restarting the terminal in Visual code the path variable was not set so just used plain old powershell to run the script.

Comment: You need to restart the terminals after editing the PATH, but I would recommend just using sarama library instead if you keep having gcc issues

Comment: did try restarting the terminal but still facing the same issue @OneCricketeer

Comment: According to the edit, that resolved the problem

Comment: Please put your solution below rather than edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by restarting the terminal The issue was even after restarting the terminal in Visual code the path variable was not set so just used plain old powershell to run the script.